# AWS instance (Jupyter notebook) stops responding

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, pyspark, jupyter

I set up a new Ubuntu instance on AWS EC2. I SSH to the instance using a private key pair. I installed python, jupyter, pyspark and all the necessary modules. I then start a Jupyter notebook using tmux.

My main aim is simply to run pyspark on an AWS instance (using Jupyter). Unfortunately, I keep running into problems with stability of the Jupyter notebook/connection to the instance. After running the Jupyter notebook for some time (sometimes 5 minutes, other times 2 hours+), it ends up "disconnecting". The kernel in the Jupyter disconnects and then does not process any further calls. At that point, I cannot SSH into the instance (just hangs -> blank screen).

I tried running the same setup on GCP but run into the same symptoms.

Is there something basic that I am missing?
Why would I not be able to SSH into the instance?
Is it possible that the Ubuntu server is crashing?

Comment: there's not even details here. What do you see in the error logs?

Comment: I have the same problem. If it helps here are the Jupiter logs at the end when the instance and Jupiter become unresponsive:

```
[I 09:19:13.329 NotebookApp] Saving file at /xxxx.ipynb
[W 09:22:24.655 NotebookApp] WebSocket ping timeout after 106503 ms.
[I 09:22:29.658 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for XXXX-XXX-...
[W 09:57:10.290 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 13 (not connected): [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:1091)
```